# Outlook addin DisplayDialogAsync iFrame not showing page

Tags: authentication, iframe, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

I have the following issue:

I'm using the DisplayDialogAsync function in my addin to launch auth from custom provider.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
  url,
  {width: 400, height: 844, displayInIframe: true},
  function (asyncResult) {
    dialog = asyncResult.value;
    dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageRecieved, processMessage);
  }
);
```

When the user is already logged in auth redirects me to specified endpoint and the Iframe closes whilst passing the token -> so everything works fine.

Yet when the user is not logged in the auth page is not displayed in the IFrame.

I've checked for the  x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN header and the provider does not set it.

The domain of the auth provider is added in the manifest.xml

So I can't figure out why is the auth page not showing.

Answer (score 0):

had to open an endpoint from the same domain as parent in the IFrame that would run the office script and then redirect to the auth provider site.